# Simple command line to compare files with ignore line endings

Tags: beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

Where can I find example command lines for Beyond Compare 4? I do not find them in the product help information.

I want to compare two (2) files with ignore line ending differences. I do not want a GUI to appear. I just want to get the exit code.

What am I missing? I was expecting the exit code of the second compare to be non-zero.

```
 Directory of C:\src\ttt

2019-01-09  13:26               290 t.txt
2019-08-09  09:21                18 u.txt
2020-07-24  16:22                28 w.txt

C:\src\ttt>"C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\bcompare.exe" /quickcompare t.txt t.txt
C:\src\ttt>ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
0
C:\src\ttt>"C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\bcompare.exe" /quickcompare t.txt w.txt
C:\src\ttt>ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare two files from the command line using Beyond Compare, then return rules-based comparison results as an exit code, use the **/quickcompare** command line argument.

```
bcomp.com /quickcompare file1.txt file2.txt
```

[Beyond Compare 4 Help - Command Line Reference](https://www.scootersoftware.com/v4help/command_line_reference.html)

> /qc=, /quickcompare=
>
> Performs a quick comparison of two files and sets the DOS error level
> on exit.  The specified type can be size, crc, or binary.  If a type
> is not specified, a rules-based comparison will be performed.  Error
> levels are documented below.
>
> Return codes
>
> 0 Success 1 Binary same 2 Rules-based same 11 Binary differences 12
> Similar 13 Rules-based differences 14 Conflicts detected 100 Unknown
> error 101 Conflicts detected, merge output not written 102 BComp.exe
> unable to wait until BCompare.exe finishes 103 BComp.exe cannot find
> BCompare.exe 104 Trial period expired 105 Error loading script file
> 106 Script syntax error 107 Script failed to load folders or files

Comment: Many thanks for your speedy answer, Chris. If I missed it in the documentation, please tell me where to find it. If I did not miss it in the documentation, perhaps a few example command lines could be added. It seems that every time I look into BC I am even more impressed with the extent of its capabilities. I'm looking forward to being able to compare database schemas and possibly tables.